# Select the class of an element on mouseover D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a very easy problem but I couldn't find the solution. I made a groups of circles each one with a class assigned. On mouseOver, I want to change the properties of the all the circles with the same class that the circle where the mouse is over.

this is my code

```
svg.selectAll(".filas")
                    .data(new Array(18))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class","filas")
                    .attr("transform", function (d,i) { return "translate(400," + ((20*i)+20) + ")";})
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(function () {
                        return new Array(4);
                    })
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("cy", 0)
                    .attr("cx", function (d,i) {return -1 * (i+4) * 30;})
                    .attr("r", 10);

        //set classes to circles

                svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .attr("class", function(d) {
                        return (d) ? "fp_" + d : null;
                    })
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    ;



                function mouseover(clase) {

                         svg.selectAll(".fp_K")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(500)
                            .style("opacity", .2);
```

I added .on("mouseover", mouseover) for each circle but I don't know how to write the function. So far I achieved change the property only for the class which is selected in the function mouseover.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the whole code

http://jsfiddle.net/ploscri/t5ams/

Comment: Please format your code better in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
svg.selectAll(".fp_K")
```

to

```
svg.selectAll("." + this.getAttribute('class'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `selection.filter(selector)`

```js
circles.on('mouseover', function() { 
  var self      = d3.select(this),
      c         = self.attr('class'),
      selection = circles.filter(function() {
        return d3.select(this).attr('class') === c;
      });
});
```

Think you can take it from here?